# Best way to get the entire bitcoin transaction history

Tags: bitcoin-core, api

From my understanding that the entire bitcoin transaction history is stored in every client. I'm looking into ways to get this information out and get them into databases or simply csv files.

I have checked out this repository on github:
https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe

But it seems it has not been updated for a while, and it mentions

> Prior to Bitcoin v0.8, this assumption seemed safe. Abe may need some fixes to >avoid skipping blocks while current and future Bitcoin versions run.

I'm wondering if there is other tools for getting the entire transaction history out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing that.
You can read blocks directly from the disk and process them or you can ask a Bitcoin client (like Bitcoin Core, for example) for the info via RPC calls.
The second way is easier but it may be slower.

```
For each block get all the hashes
 For each hash get details and write to your choice of storage
```

There are RPC call for each of the actions.
Just type help into the console in a Bitcoin client and you can see them all.